# convert string date to numeric for all values in column using pandas python

Tags: python, string, date, pandas, numeric

I need to transform "Jan 11, 2017 9:00 PM" to 2017-01-11 21:00:00 for all values in ColumnA.

Is there an easy way / function for doing this in python using pandas?

Comment: `to_datetime` seems to handle this just fine: `In [6]:

pd.to_datetime('Jan 11, 2017 9:00 PM')
Out[6]:
Timestamp('2017-01-11 21:00:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) seems to handle this just fine:

```
In [6]:
pd.to_datetime('Jan 11, 2017 9:00 PM')

Out[6]:
Timestamp('2017-01-11 21:00:00')
```

So you can just overwrite your column using the output from this function:

```
df['ColumnA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnA'])
```

And just to clarify that the dates and months are correct here:

```
In [8]:
pd.to_datetime('Jan 11, 2017 9:00 PM').day

Out[8]:
11

In [9]:
pd.to_datetime('Jan 11, 2017 9:00 PM').month

Out[9]:
1
```